# XCTest fails with error "Class AXAccessQueue is implemented in both ..."

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode10, xcuitest

XCTest fails with the following error. Test runs fine until it navigates to a page and then following error is shown in logs while trying to lookup for any element on that page.

When tried to access that page manually, it works fine without any issues. Voice over also works fine. Error occurs only while running test.

> objc[51026]: Class AXAccessQueue is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
>   (0x12f627780) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AXHearingSupport.framework/AXHearingSupport
>   (0x139359888). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> objc[51026]: Class AXAccessQueueTimer is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
>   (0x12f624d50) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AXHearingSupport.framework/AXHearingSupport
>   (0x1393598d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Tried with Xcode 10 & 10.1, simulators iphone 8, 8 plus, XR.

Comment: It only happen on simulators.